# How to create project which extends view interface of Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I like to implement Mandelbrot fractal application for learning Android. I have seen some example, In which the application extends "android.view.View" interface.( not "android.app.Activity" interface). In eclipse, with Android 3.2, How can I create a project which extends "android.view.View" interface?

See this. [Color gradient for Mandelbrot Android application doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848827/color-gradient-for-mandelbrot-android-application-doesnt-work)

thank you,
Regards,
Robo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. `View` corresponds to GUI element like button or text field. Activity is a part of application that is responsible for displaying a GUI and managing its lifecycle. You can visit the [Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html) for further explanation.

In the example you provided the View was definitely a part of layout of some Activity.

By the way, Activity and View aren't interfaces, the are classes. The *[interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)* word has a special meaning in Java: it is a declaration of operations that can be performed on the object that implements the interface but the actual implementation should be provided by the class of the object

Comment: Yes..We have to create another class to implement "android.view" in addition to main class which extends "android.activity".