# Java divison with two integer operands not working?

Tags: java, math

For some reason my math just returns 0. The value are set, I have checked.

```
int currentSize = 4079;
int totalSize = 500802;

int percentage = ((currentSize/totalSize) * 100);
progdialog.setProgress(percentage);
```

Percentage always equals percentage.
Why?

Comment: Lemme guess: `currentSize` and `totalSize` are both integers...

Comment: @Mysticial Yes, It's been a WHILE since I've programmed in Java and I know it's going to be extremely stupid.

EDIT: Oh my god. Wow. It needs to be a decimal, doesn't it?

Comment: I want to start making up syntax in answers, like "Just use `currentSize.0 / totalSize.0`".

Comment: or you could do (currentSize * 100) / totalSize if all you want is a whole number percentage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem, as other have pointed out, is integer division will turn anything less than 1 to zero. This happens before multiplying by 100. You can change the order of operations to get something better:

```
int percentage = currentSize * 100 / totalSize;
```

If you are concerned about rounding, you can use

```
int percentage = (currentSize * 100 + (totalSize >> 1)) / totalSize;
```

These avoid the expense of working with double or float values.

Comment: @agksmehx - In the first example, the multiplication happens first, so division by `totalSize` gives you an int percentage value, which is what OP wants. (Multiplying before dividing is a way to avoid integer division giving a premature zero value.) The second does the same thing but adds half of `totalSize` to the numerator so that after the division, it's like having added 0.5 before taking the integer part of the result.

Comment: +1 this answer if you've ever seen a program grind to a halt because of a tight loop of floating point division for a progress bar.

Comment: Nice trick, but a more general answer would have been nice too - eg, how to force a floating point division given integer operands.  (arrived here via google search, looking for the general answer)

Comment: @Phil - The point here was to _avoid_ floating point operations, not to force them! :) But to address your objective: to force an operation to be carried out in floating point, just force at least one of the operands to be a `float` (by casting, say). Note that it does no good to cast the result—it's the operator types that are important.  For a multi-operator expression, an analysis of operator precedence will let you determine which operand(s) need to be coerced to `float` so that all the operations that need to be done in floating point are actually carried out in floating point.

Answer (score 4):

you are using 'int's for currentSize and totalSize which results in *integer division* which removes the fractional part, yielding 0.  hence the percentage is always 0.

change it to `float percentage = (((float)currentSize/totalSize) * 100);` and things will be fine

Comment: the resulting percentage variable also needs to be a float or double, else it will still be zero if the percentage is less than 1 like in the example.

Comment: Wow. Three answers in 1 minute. Thanks guys. Logical error. It's 3am here.

Comment: correct - changed it to `float percentage = (((float)currentSize/totalSize) * 100);`

Comment: I believe it would be better to have the constant 100 as 100.0 as well, so that it is used as a double in the calculation

Comment: ted hopp above has a better answer (in case you decide to accept an answer, i. e.)

Answer (score 1):

I assume `currentSize` and `totalSize` are `int`.

```
currentSize = 4079;
totalSize = 500802;
```

If they are, then `currentSize/totalSize` is an integer division. The result will have no fractional part (the fractional part is removed, no round up). Therefore the result is `0`.

If one of the operand is double, the result of division will have fraction. Therefore, I cast one integer operand to double.

```
(double) currentSize
```

After the calculation, if you want the result to store in `int`, you have to cast (convert double to int; remove fractional part).

```
int percentage = (int) ((double) currentSize ...
```

The whole code is:

```
int currentSize = 3;
int totalSize = 100;

int percentage = (int) ((double) currentSize / totalSize * 100);
System.out.println(percentage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the result of your calculation is a double with value less than 1. You put it in an integer so it truncates everything behind the decimal separator, resulting in zero. Try storing the value in a double instead.

Answer (score 0):

If currentSize and totalSize are integers, this calculation will do [integer division,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144610/java-integer-division-how-do-you-produce-a-double) which will truncate your fraction down to 0. Use doubles.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
double percentage = ((double)(currentSize/totalSize) * 100);
progdialog.setProgress(percentage);
```

Hope it will help yout. :)

Comment: That won't help if `currentSize` and `totalSize` are int values. The conversion to `double` will only happen at the end of the (integer) operations on the right.

Answer (score 0):

```
  double occupancyRate = 0.0;
  int occupiedRoomsTotal = 12;
  int totalRooms = 20;

  occupancyRate = (((double) occupiedRoomsTotal / totalRooms)) * 100;
  DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
  System.out.println("Occupancy Rate = " + df2.format(occupancyRate) + "%");
```

Answer (score -1):

Java Division of integers yields zero if both numerator and denominator are both integers and the result is less than 1.
Fix:

Make either of the operands to be floating number or double
e.g. int x = 1;
     double y = 3.0;

x/y  gives 0.333333

where as 1/3 results in 0.

Comment: don't you mean `float x = 1.0f; float y = 3.0f;` ?

Comment: `int y=3.0` will turn it into `3`, and `x/y` will still be integer division.  You would want to say `double y=3.0`.  But this has already been answered several times, so I don't know that your answer adds anything here.

Comment: @nollyd   int x = 1 and double y = 3.0