# How To Solve Mathematical Expression In Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to get percentage but the result is error, i have expression as:

```
Uper=(Upcount/total)*100;
```

where `Uper` is float while `Upcount` and `total` is integer i am getting the result `Uper=0`.

Comment: there is not ant error in code i am just getting "0 " vlaue ??

Comment: See
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144610/java-integer-division-how-do-you-produce-a-double

Comment: can u pls mention the values of variables ???

Comment: If `Upcount` and `total` are both `int` you will receive integer division, probably 0. Better make Uper double and do `(Upcount*100.0)/total`. Naming convention would be **uper** and **upcount**.

Comment: Did you find an appropriate answer?

Answer (score 3):

An `int` divided by an `int` will result in an `int`. That could be `0`. Multiply `0 * 100`, convert to `float`, and the result is still `0.0`. You need at least one of the operands to be floating point before the division will give a floating point result.

Try:

```
Uper = ((float)Upcount/(float)total)*100.0;
```

The extra `(float)` is me being paranoid that this line might be modified in the future without fully understanding the floating-point requirement. The `100.0` is to be explicit about what you want -- a floating point result.

Perhaps changing `Upcount` or `total` to `float` would make more sense.

Comment: If at least one member of the mathematical operation is a Float/Double then the result will always be a Float/Doube. No need to pe paranoid and add 3 casts when you can do it with 1 cast only

Comment: There's only two casts. Yes, it's a bit noisy to read but in my experience code changes often over time, sometimes with brute-force search and replace mechanisms, and someone comes along later to fix compile errors without necessarily understanding the _reason_ for code to be written in a certain way. Write whatever makes the most sense for _you_ -- as I've written this code in the manner I think gives it the best chance of surviving maintenance programmers for a decade to come.

Comment: You are right about everyone writing the way they like but in the problem we have here, it is not relating to a programming language, it is rather a basic concept of Computers because the division differs between integers and floating point values. So the automation part is not required but by the machine itself for computing purposes

Answer (score 2):

the division of 2 integers will always result in an integer which is 0 in your case.

To solve this, use the following code:

```
Uper = ((Double) Upcount) / total * 100
```

Casting at least 1 member to Double or Float will get the result you want