# Math.ceil returning 0.0?

Tags: java, math

So I'm working on a Java project, and I type this:

```
double totalPages;
int amountKits = 2;
totalPages = amountKits / 3;
System.out.println("Total pages before ceil: " + totalPages);
totalPages = Math.ceil(totalPages);
System.out.println("Amount of Kits: " + amountKits);
System.out.println("Total Pages: " + totalPages);
```

And here is the result:

```
Total pages before ceil: 0.0
Amount of Kits: 2
Total Pages: 0.0
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?
(Sorry, I'm a noob, I know)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Integer Division, How do you produce a double?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144610/java-integer-division-how-do-you-produce-a-double)

Answer (score 8):

Because you're calculating `2 / 3` in integer arithmetic.

Try:

```
totalPages = amountKits / 3.0;
```

instead.

Comment: @LouisWasserman O.P. doesn't have the minimum reputation required to accept answers yet. :-\.

Comment: Wait, what?  The list of privileges I see that come with reputation doesn't seem to set a minimum reputation level to accept answers.

Answer (score 3):

`2/3` is **integer division** that returns 0. This then gets converted to a floating point value, 0.0 when you assign to `totalPages`.

You need to perform floating point division, for example by writing `amountKits/3.0`.