# Odd behaviors when dividing doubles in Java

Tags: java, double, divide

When I divide 317 by 219 in Java using doubles I get 1.
For example:

```
double b = 317/219;
System.out.println(b);
```

Output is: 1.

Is this because it is a recurring decimal?
Have had to use BigDecimal instead which is annoying.

Comment: output will be 1.0 to be more precise

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Integer division: How do you produce a double?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144610/java-integer-division-how-do-you-produce-a-double).  I took my choice, but this question is asked way too many times on SO.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this

```
 double b = 317/219D;
```

The default type of coded numbers in java is `int`, so with the code as you have it java is working with two `int` numbers and the result of the division would then be `int` too, which will truncate the decimal part to give a final result of `1`. This `int` result is then cast from `int 1` to a `double 1` without a compiler warning because it's a *widening* cast (one where the source type is guaranteed to "fit" into the target type).

By coding either of the numbers as `double` with the trailing `D` (you may also use `d`, but I always use upper case letters because `L` as lowercase `l` looks like a `1`), the result of the division will be `double` too.

Comment: Most other answers just stick `.0` to force floating point (double) arithmetic, but this answer explicitly states both operands to be of type double; a subtle but significant point!

Comment: I was sure I'd tried casting to double! Guess I was just being stupid. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Joe You need to explicitly cast one of the inputs to the division -- the implicit cast done by the assignment is equivalent to `(double) (317 / 219)` which, when it's written like that, clearly doesn't do what you want. If you do `(double) a / b`, that should work (casts have higher precedence than division, so it's interpreted as `((double) a) / b`, which isn't the case in all languages)

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative...

```
double b = (double)317/219;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have used integer literals, so you're doing an integer division.

Try writing `double b = 317.0/219.0;` instead.

Answer (score 2):

It is worth mentioning that there is no division in your example at runtime.  317/219 is calculated at compile-time (integer division, fraction is discarded) and replaced with a constant. If you decompile .class (I used Jad http://www.kpdus.com/jad.html) you will see

```
double b = 1.0D;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is `int` dividing. Write:

```
double b = 317.0/219;
System.out.println(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

since numbers you put are inetgers so is the answer.
to get double you need either to use a number with floating point or to cast one of the integers you use:

```
double b = 317.0/219;
System.out.println(b);
```

or:

```
double b = ((double)317)/219;
System.out.println(b);
```

Answer (score -3):

You could try

```
double b = 0.0;
b = 317/219;
```

so that i can return the decimal point

Comment: This is not the right answer. 
both 317 and 219 are int therefore the result will be the int part of the division not matter what is the parameter type.

Comment: There can be many things you can try other than above. However @Joe had been having trouble understanding how arithmatic stuff works in Java. This shouldn't be an answer at all.