# Unexplainable behavior of a double

Tags: java, double

I currently programming some calculations and found a weird issue, which I cannot explain.
I'm doing a calculation which I save in a new double field. The thing is, that the finally saved value is not the same than the solution of the formula. I made a screenshot for better understanding.

When I put the whole calculation in a watch, I get the result "1.3050....."
When i check the double afterwards, it has saved "2.87......." which I have no idea, where that comes from.
Does anybody know, why it is behaving like this? For me thats absolutely unexplainable...
[image]

Full size: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nJpn.png

Comment: Please post some code, not a screenshot. Can you not see that it's impossible to see what you have coded?

Comment: You can see it better if you copy picture URL and post in a new tab, but yeah, code is better..  With that said, I'm not sure what's really going on, but the Math.PI/180 would be better as Math.PI/180.0.   You also didn't tell us the value of Constants.CAM_OFFSET

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawksNot only useful, that was actually the problem... thanks for the hint :)

Comment: Alright I'll submit it as an answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Odd behaviors when dividing doubles in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668007/odd-behaviors-when-dividing-doubles-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math.PI/180 should be Math.PI/180.0, dividing doubles by integers will cause some funny things to happen

Comment: The question is tagged as "java", and Java double/int converts the int to double and does the divide. 180 is exactly representable as a double. I expect only the normal double rounding issues.

Comment: Well, apparently it fixed it, so i dunno

Comment: I just printed Math.PI/180 and Math.PI/180.0. They are exactly equal.

Comment: One possibility is that the OP had an old .class file, and making **any** change would have caused recompilation and fixed the problem.