# Final variable casting in Java

Tags: java, casting, final

```
final double integer = 20/100;
```

If i was to print integer, I would get 0 rather than 0.2

```
double integer1 = 20/100;
```

If I was to print integer1, I would get 0.2

```
final double integer3 = 200/100;
```

If I was to print integer3 out, I would get 2.0.

Can anyone explain why I get 0 for the first print statement and not 0.2 since its a double, and why it works for the third statement, where I got 2.0 as the result.

Comment: Try `20.0` in your first expression.

Comment: `double integer1 = 20/100;` returns `0.0` for me (not `0.2`).

Comment: Actually this is probably a better duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668007/odd-behaviors-when-dividing-doubles-in-java