# Dividing 2 numbers not returning right

Tags: java, android, double, division

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Integer division: How do you produce a double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144610/java-integer-division-how-do-you-produce-a-double)

When I'm dividing 2 numbers to try and get something like .90, I keep getting either 1.0 or 0.0

```
int number1 = 6517253;
int number2 = 7195629;
double number3 = number1 / number2; //returns 0.0 supposed to be 0.9057239 and I want 0.90
double number4 = number2 / number1; //returns 1.0 supposed to be 1.1040893 and don't really want that one
```

does the same thing if I change double to float.

Comment: `double number3 = (double)number1 / number2;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should convert one of the operands to `double`. Try:

```
double number3 = (double) number1 / number2;
double number4 = (double) number2 / number1;
```

This is because Java infers the type of `int / int` as `int`, but, the type of `double / int` is inferred as `double`.

Answer (score 0):

convert one of the numbers to double:

```
     double number3 = number1 / (double) number 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Every operation on literals or integer variables in java returns a integer type(uint32) so you need to typecast your operation

```
double number3 = (double)number1/number2;
```