# Java, returning a value from a method

Tags: java, methods, return, return-value

Im doing a simple piece of java code here, it is a method being called to convert Fahrenheit into Celsius. However when ever i run it, the output is always `0.0`.

I cant get it to output the correct calculation. There is probably some silly little thing i have forgotten to do, can someone please help me?

```
public class ExampleQ {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(Celsius(50));
    }

    public static double Celsius(double F)
    {
        return (5 / 9) * (F - 32);
    }
}
```

Comment: you'd be surprised, but 5/9 == 0 in Java :) 5.0/9 is not though..

Comment: And not only in Java :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is [Integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144610/java-integer-division-how-do-you-produce-a-double).

In Java `5 / 9 = 0`

Try:

```
return (5.0 / 9) * (F - 32);
```

Comment: Awesome, i knew it was something small like that, i dont usually get stumped on things like that. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

***(5/9)***  produce an integer division with the result "0". As a result it produce 0 for whole expression. Try

```
return (5.0 / 9) * (F - 32);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution. **Tested at online compiler Ideone  http://ideone.com/zRyG80**

Just replace `return (5 / 9) * (F - 32);` with `return (F - 32) * 5 / 9;`

**Because the reason is in the order of operators execution. In your code division is performed before multiplication which is making 5/9  = 0.**

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {

        System.out.println(Celsius(50));
    }

    public static double Celsius(double F) {
        return (F - 32) * 5 / 9;
    }
}
```

Output

10.0

Comment: +1 for provinding link of an online compiler and debugging tool

Answer (score 3):

`5 / 9` returns 0, since you're performing **integer** division.

Use `5.0 / 9.0` instead

Answer (score 2):

(5/9) is interpreted as integer and rounded to 0.0.

To avoid integer you can replace it with (5.0/9).

Answer (score 2):

Or else you can use below code

```
return (5d / 9d) * (F - 32);
```