# logical issue in recursion euler

Tags: java, recursion

I'd like to the euler number e for a number n inputed by the user, there's something wrong with the logical part, I can't seem to get the correct answer of 2.5 when inputting 2, instead i get 2. In fact I always get an answer of 2 no matter what the input is. The problem is in the euler method because the factorial prints the correct answer.
here is the code.

```
import java.util.*;

 public class pract5ex3 {
    public static int fact (int n){
    if (n==0 || n==1){
            return 1;
    }
    else {
    return n*fact(n-1);
    }

}
public static double constantRec(int n){
    if (n == 0){

    return 1;
    }
    else {

    return 1/fact(n)+constantRec(n-1);
    }
}

public static void main (String []args) {
    Scanner s= new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("enter number");
    int n =s.nextInt();

    int factorial = pract5ex3.fact(n);
    double euler = pract5ex3.constantRec(n);
    System.out.println(factorial);
    System.out.println(euler);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Beware of [Integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144610/java-integer-division-how-do-you-produce-a-double).

Use:

```
1.0/fact(n)
```

To get the double value.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `1/fact(n)` does integer division which will yield zero if factorial is greater than one. Simply change it to `1.0/fact(n)`.