# Division not working with an array length JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, debugging

I'm trying to divide two numbers to get a percentage, then print it. Here's the relevant method:

```
public void process_winner(String candidates[], int votes[])
{
   double percent = (mostVotes / votes.length) * 100;
   if (mostVotes > votes.length / 2)
      System.out.println("Winner: " + candidates[mostVotesIndex] + "(" + percent + "%)");
   else
      System.out.println("None (no majority)");
   System.out.println("");
}
```

the problem line is:

```
double percent = mostVotes / votes.length;
```

`mostVotes` is an `int`, with a value of 6, and `votes.length` is 10. I verified this using the debugger.

It's showing a value of 0.0 for my percent variable, when it should show 60.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to cast to `double`, or change the operation order.

Do this:

```
double percent = (mostVotes * 100 ) / votes.length;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast it to `double`, because otherwise it will be an *integer division*, and thus, the precision will be lost.

```
double percent = ((double) mostVotes / votes.length) * 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is [Integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3144617/1651233), and works as expected.
If you want to get `double` value when dividing integers, use:

```
double percent = mostVotes * 1.0 / votes.length;
```

BTW, in order to get percentage, you need to multiple it by 100:

```
double percent = mostVotes * 100.0 / votes.length;
```

Answer (score 1):

make your formule as `(mostvotes * 100)/votes.length`
In your case, the execution is:

- `mostVotes/votes.length` causes 6/10 which is integer division
- 6/10 = 0
- 0 * 100 gives result 0

When you change it to `double percent = (mostVotes * 100 ) / votes.length;`

The order of execution becomes

- `mostVotes * 100` i.e. 6 * 100
- 6 * 100 = 600.
- `600/votes.length` i.e. 600/10 = 60

This should give you correct output

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this or "cast" it to a double. 
what you have done is this

```
 double percent = (mostVotes / votes.length) * 100;
```

what you think you are doing is this:

- (6/10) = 0.6
- 0.6*100 = 60

now what is actually happening is this:

- (6/10) = 0  <--- this is becasue it is an "Integer" division meaning it is not capable of dividing and creating a double data value. What it will do is change it to zero because an integer cannot produce a decimal digit
- Therefore , 0*100 = gives you a 0 at the end

Know after explaining what you have done wrong i will explain what is right, and explain it to you.

- you first "multiply" mostvotes with 100: (mostVotes*100) now this will create a full number; an integer.
- now 6*100 = 600.
- we then divide that with votes.length, which is "10"
- we then recieve 60. <--- which is your answer.

  (mostVotes*100) / votes.length

The reason behind this is because you never really meet a decimal number in this way of calculation.

1. you first 6*100 = 600 <--- no decimal (no double involved)
2. Then you do 600/10 = 60 <--- no decimal (no double involved)

You of course can just change mostVotes into a double. But doing this is just a more convienent way.

This is more of a "algorithmic problem" and not a progrtamming problem.