# Not return full decimal number

Tags: java

I Just want to print full result of following equation:

```
float rate = (interestRate / 1200);

double rate = (interestRate / 1200);
```

where `interestRate` is `5`. My problem is it always showing same value 0.0 instead 0.00416666666667 not matter which datatype I use from double or float.

How can I get full result of this simple equation? please help.

Comment: I hope you do not use this formula to calculate the monthly interest rate?

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast (at least) one of the divisors:

```
double rate = ((double) interestRate / 1200);
```

Comment: aah, I missed that, how silly I am. Thanks for your valuable answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is called [Integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144610/java-integer-division-how-do-you-produce-a-double).

You can either cast:

```
double rate = ((double)interestRate / 1200);
```

or use:

```
double rate = (interestRate / 1200.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

your issue is related to the fact that you are performing a division between `integer`. You have to cast at least one of the two operands

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast:

```
float rate = 0.0f;
float rate = ((float) interestRate / 1200);
```