# Java - Costum Classes, code not working

Tags: java, class

For some reason when I run the file the answer seems to be 0. I'm still fairly new to Java so could someone explain to me what I've done wrong.. It all seems fine to me.

```
public class bus {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    bus fivePM = new bus(23, 120);
    bus elevenAM = new bus(27, 140);

    System.out.println(fivePM.gallonsUsed());
    System.out.println(elevenAM.gallonsUsed());
}
private int mpg;
private int milesTravelled;
private double used;

public bus(int mpg, int milesTravelled){
     this.mpg = mpg;
     this.milesTravelled = milesTravelled;

}
public double gallonsUsed(){
    this.used = this.mpg/this.milesTravelled;
    return this.used;
 }
}
```

Comment: Search for integer division vs double division.

Comment: int/int = int . Check your division part

Comment: Your code is broken if `milesTravelled` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

In both of your instantiated bus objects, milesTravelled is less than mpg.

When you divide an int by an int, you get an int.

```
this.mpg/this.milesTravelled;
```

This will return 0 because the digits after the decimal point don't matter if it's an int.

To make them not ints, you could do things like:

```
this.mpg * 1.0 / this.milesTravelled
```

or

```
this.mpg/((double) this.milesTravelled)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `double` instead of `int` or just carefully convert your `int` into a `double` before doing any division.  This is a common problem for Java novices.  Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144610/java-integer-division-how-do-you-produce-a-double) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java).  Try this out:

```
private double mpg;
private double milesTravelled;
private double used;

public bus(double mpg, double milesTravelled){
     this.mpg = mpg;
     this.milesTravelled = milesTravelled;
}
```

**NOTE 1**:  When you do the division, make sure you check to see if `milesTravelled` is equal to 0 or not.  If it is, then you will get an `Exception`.

**NOTE 2**:  Change `bus` to `Bus` in the header definition of `bus` (which then means you will use `Bus` instead of `bus`).  Using the capital letter in the beginning of a custom Object's name is a relatively common standard.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, diving ints gives an integer number. You can change type types of `mpg` and `milesTravelled` to double.  Also you should be inverting the answer.  m/g divided by m = m/mg = 1/g, not g. For example, at 10mpg traving 20m would use 2 gallons, but your calculation would give 1/2 gallon.