# Java division of numbers

Tags: java, exception, decimal-point

Below is the code, when i divide 5/6,it shows 0.0 output rather 0.8333.

```
package sunday;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class exception {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int donut,milk;
        double donutperglass;
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        try{
            System.out.println("enter donut");
            donut=in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("enter milk");
            milk=in.nextInt();

            if(milk<1)
                throw new Exception("no milk");

            donutperglass=donut/milk;
            System.out.println(donutperglass);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("go buy some milk");
        }
        System.out.println("end");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
    }    
}
```

Comment: I hate it when I forget something little like this.

Answer (score 3):

Change the data types of `donut` and `milk` to double.

So that it will return the double value instead of int.

See this question for more details

[Integer division: How do you produce a double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144610/java-integer-division-how-do-you-produce-a-double)

Answer (score 0):

Declare `donut` and `milk` as double type too if you want double type `dounutperglass` after division.

Answer (score 0):

Data type should be changed to double.

Reason : int cannot hold the floating values.

int/int gives int only. Change the data types of donut and milk to double.

double/double gives you the exact result

Answer (score 0):

You must cast one of the terms to a floating point value, instead of int.

By example:

`donutperglass=((double) donut)/milk;`