# The output of this loop should be less than 1, but I get very large numbers

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop

This program is supposed to count the number of characters "c" and "g" in genes in the DNA string and then take that number and divide it by the length of each gene. The number of cs and gs is always < gene.length(), therefore the output should be something like 0.65555, 0.35657 etc, but I get large numbers like 141, etc. Not sure what is wrong with this loop.

```
public void testfile(){
    String dnaTest = "aaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaacccttaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctaaccctcacccttctaact";


    int counter = 0;
        for(String gene : s1.data()) {

            for (char cORg : gene.toCharArray()) {
                if ((cORg == 'c') || (cORg == 'g')) {
                    counter ++;
                 }

              System.out.print(gene +" ");

            }
            float cgRatioGenes =  counter/gene.length();
            System.out.println("cgRatio:  " + cgRatioGenes);
        }
    }
}
```

If you spot the error, let me know. Thanks!

**EDIT**

Even without the parentesis at the end of the DNA string and with the closing bracket, the loop was not producing the results I expected. Therefore, it is not off topic.

Comment: What's s1? Also, gene.length() where is this variable?

Comment: q1: what is "s1.data()"?
q2: if you divide an int by an int the result is int. please cast at least one of them to float before division.

Comment: Won't compile because s1 is not defined.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to compute and print `cgRatioGenes` within the outermost `for` loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integer division: How do you produce a double?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144610/integer-division-how-do-you-produce-a-double)

Comment: Won't compile because of a `)` at the end of the `dnaTest` line. What is the purpose of that `dnaTest` anyway? It is unused by displayed code.

Comment: @Andreas it's a typo. There shoulddn't be a quote at the and. I decided not to remove the DNA string, because some people who view this question may not know what it looks like. I figured it'd be easier to imagine what I was talking about.

Comment: Please provide a link to example on http://ideone.com/

Comment: The loop would't work even without the ')' at the end of the DNA string. It is not off topic. @Chloe. The answer provided by resueman fixed the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems:

First, you never reinitialize `counter` when you start the loop again. Move that declaration inside the loop so that each repetition starts with a counter of zero.

If you make that change, all your results will be zero though, because you're diving two integers, which will truncate the results. Cast one to float, so that it keeps the decimal part. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144610/integer-division-how-do-you-produce-a-double) for more information on the problem

```
for(String gene : s1.data()) {
    int counter = 0; //Moved inside the for loop, so that it always starts at 0
    for (char cORg : gene.toCharArray()) {
        if ((cORg == 'c') || (cORg == 'g')) {
            counter ++;
        }

        System.out.print(gene +" ");
    }

    //Floating point division, instead of integer division
    float cgRatioGenes =  ((float)counter)/gene.length(); 
    System.out.println("cgRatio:  " + cgRatioGenes);
}
```

Comment: And *maybe* OP got confused about code because indentations were misleading. Sure confused me for a second, since a close-brace (`}`) was missing.

Comment: Thanks! It works as intended now.

Comment: @Ekaterina1234 I know it might just be a result of copying your code into the question, but as [Andreas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) points out, make sure your indentation is correct; otherwise it's very easy to get confused.

Comment: @resueman  apologies for that, I had some other stuff in the original code, that was not relevant tho the question, so I deleted it, and probably deleted the brace as well. Next time I'll indent the code properly, so that it's easier to read. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

One potential problem is here

> float cgRatioGenes =  counter/gene.length();

As gene.length() is an integer value the ratio is not computed correctly. Instead, you should cast one of them to float like this

> float cgRatioGenes =  ((float)counter)/gene.length();

In addition, the counter variable should probably be initialized to zero for each gene (unless you want to count the c/g values over all genes).

This probably does not explain the behavior you are observing, but it is not possible to figure it out unless a complete working example is given.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what the exact intent of this code is, but my guess is that you're using one `int counter` for every gene in `s1.data()`. I assume you want to count the number of valid characters per gene, not in the entire pool.

If you do want to count for the entire pool, the problem is that you're peforming `gene.length` outside of the `for`, which should honestly throw a compiler error unless you have a `gene` defined somewhere else as well.

Additionally, you're dividing two ints for your answer, which will yield an `int`. Case one of your variables to `float` to get a decimal answer.