# Firebase database cant write data

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using google app engine + firebase database. I need to change some values in firebase database via app engine, but setValue() method does not work. No exceptions sent, i can read data, so service account is working nice.
Here is the code im using:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

  ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
        {
            if (snapshot.exists())
            {
                for (DataSnapshot childSnap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (childSnap.child("Character").exists()) {
                        int energyCurrent;
                        int energyMax;
                        int energyObtain;
                        energyCurrent = (int) (long) childSnap.child("Character").child("energyCurrent").getValue();
                        energyMax = (int) (long) childSnap.child("Character").child("energyMax").getValue();
                        energyObtain = (int) (long) childSnap.child("Character").child("energyObtain").getValue();

                        float finalEnergy = energyCurrent + (energyMax * (energyObtain / 100));
                        if (finalEnergy > energyMax) {
                            childSnap.getRef().child("Character").child("energyCurrent").setValue(energyMax, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                                    if (databaseError != null) { throw databaseError.toException(); }
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            childSnap.getRef().child("Character").child("energyCurrent").setValue((int) finalEnergy, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                                    if (databaseError != null) { throw databaseError.toException(); }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
}

Here is the scheme of my database if u need it:

    "Users" : {
        "NRPdi5gaaaaaHSfovegwg8XgFjZ2" : {
          "Character" : {
            energyCurrent : 0,
            energyMax : 100,
            energyObtain : 20,
            and other char values..
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Set some breakpoints?

Comment: @cricket_007 i think no, because i dont know what is that.)

Comment: @cricket_007 if u mean continue, break ot sth like that, then no, i didnt use it.

Comment: Breakpoints. Points in your code that you can pause and debug your application. If not, just add else statements to all the if statements and print anything  because it's clearly not entering one of them if nothing happens

Comment: @cricket_007 in the place of setValue listener i put else and else block was done, that means databaseError==null, and that means everything is ok and setValue was executed. wtf?)

Comment: By the way, you only need to do `setValue(Math.min(energyMax, finalEnergy)`. But really, `energyObtain / 100` is probably 0 and you multiply that, so still zero, then add nothing to `energyCurrent`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
energyObtain = (int) (long) childSnap.child("Character").child("energyObtain").getValue();
```

And

```
energyObtain : 20,
```

Then this just zeros out.

```
(energyMax * (energyObtain / 100));
```

So, solution... Make a proper floating point

```
energyMax * (energyObtain / 100.0)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but i cant understand why, can u give a link for the topic which can describe that? Or just in few words by yourself, please))

Comment: You truncated an integer. Integer division? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144610/integer-division-how-do-you-produce-a-double

Comment: It's a Java problem. Not related to Firebase at all