# Integer division: Why it print wrong value?

Tags: java, integer, long-integer

```
public class PragsLongDivision{

public static void main (String [] args){
 final long MICRO_PER_DAY=24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000;
 final long MILLIS_PER_DAY= 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

  System.out.println(MICRO_PER_DAY / MILLIS_PER_DAY  );

   }
}
```

This program print 5 why? Please share best salutation with reason.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144610/integer-division-how-do-you-produce-a-double

Answer (score 0):

In these lines:

```
 final long MICRO_PER_DAY=24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000;
 final long MILLIS_PER_DAY= 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

each of the constant integer numbers is of type `int` and the result calculated is also of type `int`.  
But the result you would expect: `86400000000` for `MICRO_PER_DAY` is too large to fit in the 32 bits of an `int` and it is truncated.  
This is called **Numeric Overflow**. 
To get the right result use this:

```
 final long MICRO_PER_DAY=24L * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000;
 final long MILLIS_PER_DAY= 24L * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

The `L` suffix after `24` will guide the compiler so that it does store the result in the 64 bits of type `long` and not truncate it.

Comment: It is not really about storing the result as a long that makes this work: it is that the calculation is performed using longs. A consequence is that you need to store the result as a long, but that is not the main reason.

Comment: *that the calculation is performed using longs* each calculation produces a result that is stored as long. *but that is not the main reason* what does this mean?

Comment: `long a = Integer.MAX_VALUE * Integer.MAX_VALUE;` *stores* the result as a long, but *calculates* it with ints.

Comment: `long a = Integer.MAX_VALUE * Integer.MAX_VALUE;` **finally** stores the result inside the 64 bits of a long, but this result is calculated as `int` and this is why it is wrong.