# Why don't I get any decimal place when dividing by e.g. 1000000000

Tags: java

So, I'm trying to shift the comma of an int/long like 37800 by dividing it by e.g. 1000, and saving this then into a float.

```
float shift;
shift = 37800/1000;
```

As a result I get `37.0` in this example.

What is happening there? Why do they get deleted?

Comment: Integer division truncates. Promote at least one of the operands to a float to perform floating point division: `shift = 37800/1000f;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integer division: How do you produce a double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144610/integer-division-how-do-you-produce-a-double)  - Also applies to float