# How to get Decimal part in Double variable Division[JAVA]

Tags: java, double, decimal, precision

If I divide a double type variable, the Decimal part becomes zero.

```
a=13122/10;
System.out.println (a);
```

Prints

> 1312.0

As you can see, the Decimal part became zero when I divided it.
But I need the value

> 1312.2

Comment: "If I divide a double type variable" - neither `13122` nor `10` are double, those are ints.

Comment: Or perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144610/integer-division-how-do-you-produce-a-double

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that while you may have stored "a" as a double, you are really dividing two "ints" and saving that. When you divide 2 ints, the number automatically gets rounded down. So, it's rounded down to 1312.0.

What you need is this,

```
a = (double)13122/10;
```

or this:

```
a = 13122.0/10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dividing integers. You can cast the division and then you are ok

```
double a = (double) 13122/10;
    System.out.println (a);
```